# How can i used "mvn compile" command to compile both main and test source files?

Tags: maven

The maven compiler plugin in my pom file is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-testCompile</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Now if i type "mvn compile" command then maven is able to only compile main source files only. I have to type "mvn test-compile" command to compile test classes. Is there any way by which i can compile both kind of source files with just one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, `compile` and `test-compile` are different targets. You could, however, use both in the same call: `mvn compile test-compile`.

Comment: So if i do mvn clean install -DskipTests=true, then will both phases( compile and test-compile) be execute or not ?

Comment: yes, `install`, even with the `-DskipTests` flag, build the test sources.

Comment: @Mureinik, running `mvn test-compile` is enough, as it will anyway call the `compile` phase (and any lifecycle phases prior to `test-compile`).